# How to mock mongoose chaining query with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, method-chaining

on test suite i want to mock model with chaining method `findOne` then `select`

## LoginService

```
public loggingIn = async (loginDTO: LoginDTO) => {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email : loginDTO.email }).select(['_id', 'username', 'email', 'password']);
    if (user) {
      const isPasswordMatching = await bcrypt.compare(loginDTO.password, user.password);
      if (isPasswordMatching) {
        const token = this.generateToken(user);
        const tokenDTO : TokenDTO = {
          access_token: token,
          expiresIn: loginConstant.EXPIRES_IN,
        };
        return tokenDTO;
      }
      throw new InvalidCrendentialsException();
    }
    throw new InvalidCrendentialsException();
  }
```

## test

```
it('should return access_token when login is success', async () => {
      UserModel.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(UserFactory.successResponse);
      bcrypt.compare = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
      const loginController = new LoginController();
      const app = new App([loginController]);

      const result = await request(app.getServer())
          .post(`${loginController.path}`)
          .send(loginFactory.validRequest);

      // expect(result.status).toBe(200);
      expect(result.body).toBe(200);
    });
```

errorMessage

> user_model_1.default.findOne(...).select is not a function

Answer (score 11):

For this to work, you need to define the mock so that the `findOne` method returns an object with the `select` method. An easy way to do this would be to define your mock as:

```
UserModel.findOne = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ select: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(UserFactory.successResponse)}));
```