# How to mock a MongoDB query .exec() in Jest?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jestjs, typegoose

I would like to mock this async function with **Jest in a Typescript Express env**.

```js
// src/helpers/user.ts
import { UserModel } from "../models";

export const getUserByUsername = async (username: string) => {
  return UserModel.findOne({ username }).exec()
}
```

```js
// src/models/index.ts
import { getModelForClass } from "@typegoose/typegoose";

export const UserModel = getModelForClass(User, { schemaOptions: { timestamps: true } });
```

Here is my the test that fails:

```js
// src/helpers/user.test.ts
describe("getUserByUsername():", () => {
  test('should return a user if username matches', async () => {
    const mockUser: User = await userFactory.build("user");

    const spy = jest.spyOn(UserModel, "findOne");
    spy.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(mockUser))

    const userByUsernameResult = usersHelper.getUserByUsername(mockUser.username);

    await expect(userByUsernameResult).resolves.toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ username: mockUser.username })); 
  });
});
```

The error message I get:

> expect(received).resolves.toEqual() Received promise rejected instead
> of resolved Rejected to value: [TypeError:
> models_1.UserModel.findOne(...).exec is not a function]

Could you please help me?

**UPDATE**: I use in some other tests the `MongoDB Memory Server` approach that works in this case too (see below). However, I would really like to know how to do it by mocking the `.exec()` (see above).

```js
// src/helpers/user.test.ts
beforeAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL as string, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } as ConnectOptions, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  })
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});

describe("getUserByUsername():", () => {
  test('should return a user if username matches', async () => {
    const mockUser: User = await userFactory.build("user", {}, { setId: false });

    const validUser = new UserModel(mockUser);
    await validUser.save();

    const userByUsernameResult = usersHelper.getUserByUsername(mockUser.username);

    await expect(userByUsernameResult).resolves.toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ username: mockUser.username }));
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case seems quite similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249372/how-to-mock-mongoose-chaining-query-with-jest) question.

In similarity to the answer given there, you can do:

```
UserModel.findOne = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(() => {/* Your value here.*/})}));
```

To elaborate and add some value to the answer: `exec()` is a method chained with the call on `UserModel.findOne()`. Therefore, you have to mock on two levels: one that defines a mock implementation for `UserModel.findOne()`, and one that mocks the `exec()` as a chain call with `UserModel.findOne`, specifying the value returned by it.

If you want continue mocking in the chain, you have to define a mock implementation for `exec()` as well using `mockImplementationOnce`, providing an object with the methods desired for the chain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach should work.

```js
   const findOneMock = jest.spyOn(UserModel, 'findOne');
    findOneMock.mockResolvedValueOnce({ exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser) } as any)
```

in case of type error explicit type assertions on mock object approach.

```js
    findOneMock.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser) as unknown as () => Promise<User>,
    } as any);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

`mockUser` in `jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser)` has a TS error: *Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.* 

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like there is a type mismatch. I was hoping `as any` will do the trick. Try replacing 'as any' with 'as () => Promise<User>' and see what happens. Let me know if worked and I will update my answer.

Comment: With `as () => Promise<User>'`, the TS error is now: _Conversion of type '{ exec: Mock<UnknownFunction>; }' to type '() => Promise<User>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ exec: Mock<UnknownFunction>; }' provides no match for the signature '(): Promise<User>'._

Comment: good. Now try `as unknown as () => Promise<User>`

Comment: With `findOneMock.mockResolvedValueOnce({ exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser) } as unknown as () => Promise<User>)`, the TS error is now back on `mockUser`: _Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'._

Comment: Ha ha. I have updated my initial answer with my final approach. Please check. I am out of ideas. There is some  type inference issues within your test environment that i don't understand. also, if everything fails, you can use  @ts-ignore to get rid of the error. As i understand your goal is to test your function is being called and executing with correct argument. Do try my final approach tho.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254432/discussion-between-pierre-and-nazrul-chowdhury).